# The function is $F(x,y,z) = x^2y^2z$. Curve C is the intersection of the surfaces $z=2-x^2-y^2$ and $z=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$. Calculate $\oint F ds$.

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, parametrization, scalar-fields

The function is $F(x,y,z) = x^2y^2z$. Curve C is the intersection of the surfaces $z=2-x^2-y^2$ and $z=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$. Calculate $\oint_C F ds$.

Attempt:

Firstly, to define the term inside the integral, I first find the gradient of the function, which in my case is: $\operatorname{grad}\vec F= 2xy^2z \vec i + 2x^2yz \vec j + x^2y^2 \vec k$

Next I find the intersection, for which I get the following: $2-x^2-y^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I realize that I need use parametrization, but can't figure out the expression.

Edit#1

Ok, so I tried the following parametrization
$r^2=x^2+y^2$
which gives the following:
$$r^2+r-2=0$$
$$r_1=1$$
$$r_2=-2$$

It is obvious that $r_1=1$ is the correct solution.
For $x, y, z$ I get:
$$x=r\cos t$$
$$y=r\sin t$$
$$z=r$$
$$0≤t≤2\pi$$

Their respective derivates are:
$$dx=-r\sin tdt$$
$$dy=r\cos tdt$$
$$dz=0dt$$

Now I add all these into integration formula:

$$\int 2xy^2zdx+2x^2yzdy+x^2y^2dz = \int_0^{2\pi} (-2r^5\sin^3t\cos t+2r^5\sin t\cos^3t)dt$$

The final solution is $0$, and according to the theorem, a closed line curve always gives $0$ as a solution. Can anyone confirm if this is the correct solution?

Comment: Provided you wanted to integrate $\oint_C\color{red}{\nabla}F\cdot ds$ and not $\oint_CF\, |ds|$ then zero is the correct solution. No calculation is needed. Do you know why?  On the other hand: can you think of a function $F$ where $\oint_CF\, |ds|$ can impossibly be zero? Hint: how do we calculate the length of the curve $C\,?$